# Integral equations solutions

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations

In my research, I have reached a point where I need to find a function defined on the interval $[0,\pi]$ and satisfies the following properties:

1. It's an even function:

$f(-\theta) = f(\theta)$

2. It's normalised as:

$\int^\pi_0f(\theta)d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

3. For any $\phi$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$,the following property is satisfied:

$\int^\pi_0f(\theta)f(\theta - \phi)d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} \cos^2\frac{\phi}{2}$

I have tried many functions, but non of them worked. I would be very much in your debt if you help me find such a function.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition looks strange; let's shift the limits to $-\phi$ and $-\phi + \pi$. That way we get $f(\theta)$ inside.  Now, you want that integral to have a constant value regardless of the value of $\phi$.  But that can only be satisfied by a constant function. If you shift the interval $\delta \theta$ to the right, the integral can't change, which means the area added has to equal the area lost, so the heights have to be equal.  So the first condition requires $f(\theta - \phi) = 1/2$.
Given that constraint, the second requirement is impossible to satisfy.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In fact, I have reached a similar conclusion before in the following way: $f(\theta - \phi)$ has the same graph as $f(\theta)$ only shifted horizontally. and since integrating it over the same interval must be constant, thus it must be constant, due to it having the same area over the same interval anywhere.
But too much at stake here for me, and I was hoping that maybe there's some wierd function that I am not aware of that does the trick.

Comment: I will edit the question to be more reasonable.